# htaccess file set /prod/ as /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I write the .htaccess that it removes the /prod?
I have this document tree:

```
/
  /prod
  /dev
```

now I want that my URL looks like `https://example.com` and not `https://example.com/prod` when I want to see the content of `/prod`

I already tried this but in only redirects from `/` to `/prod`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prod/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prod/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?prod$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?prod/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prod/?
RewriteRule ^ /prod%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will work likewise in the actual http server's host cnfiguration or, if you do not have access to that, in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.